# AngularJS filter causes IE8 to not render two-way binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a bizarre issue with IE8 where if I try to render a `$scope` variable in a template via AngularJS's two-way data binding, it won't replace `{{child.name}}` with the proper value.  This surely has something to do with the inefficiency of the following filter:

```
  filter('truncate', function() {
    return function(name) {
      // It's just easier to use jQuery here
      var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
          nameElement = $('a:contains("' + name + '")'),
          truncPnt = Math.floor(name.length * 0.9);

      while (nameElement.width() > windowWidth * 0.75 && truncPnt > 6) {

        truncPnt = Math.floor(truncPnt * 0.9);
        name = name.substring(0, truncPnt);
        nameElement.text(name + ' ...');
      }
      return name;
    }
  });
```

I then use this filter with an `ng-repeat` with:

```
<a class="entity-name" href="{{child.url}}" title="{{child.name}}" ng-cloak>{{child.name|truncate}}</a>
```

The overall goal is to have the variable passed into the filter truncated down depending on the width of the screen, replacing any truncated characters with " ...".  I'm fairly confident this filter is the cause since I have a similar function that gets called on a `.resize()` of the `$(window)` handler, and if I were to take IE8, and resize the browser window, it causes the `{{child.name}}` to render as the proper value, but only if I resize the browser.

**UPDATE:**

---

So I've gotten rid of the above filter, and replaced it with a very similar directive.  This is my first attempt at creating a custom directive, so I'm fairly certain it could be done better, minus the obvious flaw that I cannot seem to work around currently.  The directive is as follows:

```
.directive('truncate', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    template: '<a class="entity-name" href="{{child.url}}" title="{{child.name}}">{{child.display}}</a>',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      var widthThreshold = $(element[0]).parent().parent().width() * 0.85;

      scope.$watch('child', function(val) {
        var elementWidth = $(element[0]).width(),
            characterCount = scope.child.name.length;

        while ($(element[0]).width() > widthThreshold || characterCount > 5) {
          characterCount--;
          scope.child.display = scope.child.name.substring(0, characterCount) + ' ...';
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

And I replace the partial to simply:

```
<a truncate="child"></a>
```

The differences in this as opposed to the filter are as follows (minus the obvious filter vs. directive):

1. Replace `windowWidth` with `widthThreshold`, identifying the value by chaining jQuery's `.parent()` twice (essentially it's a more accurate value when getting the width of the parent (x2) element instead of the window).
2. Added an additional key to `child` called `display`.  This will be a truncated version of `child.name` that is used for display, instead of using jQuery's `.text()` and just rendering using a truncated `child.name`.
3. `truncPnt` becomes `characterCount` (trying to remember not to abbreviate variables)

The problem now becomes that jQuery is freezing up the browser, until I kill the javascript (if prompted).  Firefox may display it, Chrome has yet to not hang, and while I've yet to test in IE, I'd imagine worse than the former.

What can be done to properly get the value of two parents above the main element in question, and truncate `child.display` so that it will not wrap/extend past the parent div?

**UPDATE 2:**

---

I decided to ditch the thought of primarily DOM-based calculations in favor of mathematics, accounting for the width of the parent div, font size, and a ratio of God knows what.  I seriously plugged away at a formula until I got something that consistently gave similar results no matter the font size.  Media queries do impact the font-size CSS of the string in question, so I needed to account for that or else have some drastic differences in the length of the truncated string between different font-size's:

```
.directive('truncate', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    // {{child.display}} will be a truncated copy of child.name
    template: '<a class="entity-name" href="{{child.url}}" title="{{child.name}}">{{child.display}}</a>',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      var widthThreshold = $(element).parent().parent().width() * 0.85,
          // get the font-size without the 'px' at the end, what with media queries effecting font
          fontSize = $(element).css('font-size').substring(0, $(element).css('font-size').lastIndexOf('px')),
          // ... Don't ask...
          sizeRatio = 29760/20621,
          characterCount = Math.floor((widthThreshold / fontSize) * sizeRatio);

      scope.$watch('child', function(val) {
        // Truncate it and trim any possible trailing white-space
        var truncatedName = scope.child.name.substring(0, characterCount).replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
        // Make sure characterCount isn't > the current length when accounting for the '...'
        if (characterCount < scope.child.name.length + 3) {
          scope.child.display = truncatedName + '...';
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Interestingly enough, I believe I came full circle back to Brandon Tilley's comment regarding modifying the DOM versus modifying a property in the scope.  Now that I've changed it to modifying a property, it would probably better serve in a filter?  What is typically the deciding factor for whether or not this sort of manipulation should be handled in a filter versus a directive?

Comment: Since you're manipulating the DOM directly (`nameElement.text`) and not actually returning a new value to use in the text, I believe this should really be a directive.

Comment: Yeah, it does seem rather hackish.  I'm unfamiliar with directives in AngularJS. I'll go do the research.

Comment: "// ... Don't ask...
sizeRatio = 29760/20621," .. lol!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refer to the documentation:

**Directives**

> Directives are a way to teach HTML new tricks. During DOM compilation directives are matched against the HTML and executed. This allows directives to register behavior, or transform the DOM.

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

**Filters**

> Angular filters format data for display to the user. In addition to formatting data, filters can also modify the DOM. This allows filters to handle tasks such as conditionally applying CSS styles to filtered output.

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters

I would use filters only for the purpose of changing the format of data and nothing else. To be honest I believe using a filter for your purpose is appropriate. And as the docs say a filter can modify the DOM I don't see a reason why u should use a directive at all, a filter seems to be what you are looking for. (Apart from the fact that a bug may force you to use a directive)

Comment: I added the following comment to the dev_guide.templates.filters page about a month ago: "I think this text should be removed 'filters can also modify the DOM. This allows filters to handle tasks such as conditionally applying CSS styles to filtered output.'  I don't think filters do this anymore (they used to, see http://code.angularjs.org/0.9.19/docs-0.9.19/#!/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters.creating_filters)."

Comment: @MarkRajcok That may be the case but for some reasons there is no discussion displayed for me and I just quoted the docs ;) I also don't get why filters shouldn't do ANY DOM manipulation at all? If I look at this (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters.using_filters) example; doesn't it have to manipulate the DOM in some way?

Comment: yeah Disqus issues... I often have to reload a page to get the comments to load.  The 0.9 documentation for angular.filter says that coders can use the following inside the method: "this.$element — The DOM element containing the binding. The $element variable allows the filter to manipulate the DOM."  Then the example shows "this.$element.css('color', color);".  Nowadays, this kind of manipulation is done in directives, not filters.  Filters really only do 3 things now: 1) format data/output 2) select a subset of data 3) sort.  None of these are really DOM manipulation, IMO.

Comment: @MarkRajcok Selecting a subset of the data is exactly what Scott wants to do, so a filter is the thing he should go for right? I do think that this already includes DOM manipulation as u are for example changing the value of a DOM element (innerHTML() is part of the DOM right?). You are not changing the DOMs structure though, that's for sure :)

Comment: Well, the subset part sure sounds like a good match for a filter, but the "determine the width of parent elements" part doesn't.  That's one reason why I didn't try to answer this question :) Regarding innerHTML(), I tend to look at it this way:  the filter formats/subsets/sorts the data, and essentially only the text of the element is altered as a result of the filter.  When Angularians talk about "DOM manipulation", I get the impression that this type of manipulation is excluded. DOM structure changes (as you mentioned), or jQuery-like DOM traversal or manipulation seem to qualify.